# Strange value of the double type variable: -nan(0x8000000000000)

Tags: double

I am confused by the value of "currdisk->currangle" after adding. Initially the value of "currdisk->currangle" is 0.77500000000000013, but after adding operation, it's changed to "-nan(0x8000000000000)", Can anyone explain ? Thanks!  The following is the occasion of gdb debugging.

```
3338          currdisk->currangle += (simtime - seg->time) / currdisk->rotatetime;
(gdb) p currdisk->currangle
$28 = 0.77500000000000013
(gdb) p (simtime - seg->time) / currdisk->rotatetime
$29 = 0.00833333333333325
(gdb) p (simtime - seg->time) 
$30 = 0.092592592592591672
(gdb) p currdisk->rotatetime
$31 = 11.111111111111111
(gdb) p currdisk->currangle + (simtime - seg->time) / currdisk->ratetime
(gdb) n

(gdb) p currdisk->currangle 
$32 = -nan(0x8000000000000)
(gdb) p/x (char[8])currdisk->currangle 
$52 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xf8, 0xff}
(gdb)
```

Then I divide the sentence.

```
double tmp1 = (simtime - seg->time) / currdisk->rotatetime; 
currdisk->currangle += tmp1
```

The value of currdisk->currangle is normal.

```
tmp1 = (simtime - seg->time) / currdisk->rotatetime;
currdisk->currangle += tmp1;
```

The above code can also cause NaN in the later calling.

So I step into to the assembly.

```
tmp1 = (simtime - seg->time) / currdisk->rotatetime;
0x0808fdf4  <disk_buffer_sector_done+559>:  fldl   0x80b2208
0x0808fdfa  <disk_buffer_sector_done+565>:  mov    -0x38(%ebp),%eax
0x0808fdfd  <disk_buffer_sector_done+568>:  fldl   (%eax)
```

...Here, the content of %eax is 0x80bdfeb, which is the address of seg->time. 
After the above "fldl (%eax) " executed, the content of register st0 is 0x8000000000000000, which represents NaN. 
So the NaN is propagated to the following instructions. This is the key issue.
Code:

```
0x0808fdff  <disk_buffer_sector_done+570>:  fsubrp %st,%st(1)
0x0808fe01  <disk_buffer_sector_done+572>:  mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0808fe04  <disk_buffer_sector_done+575>:  fldl   0xc4(%eax)
0x0808fe0a  <disk_buffer_sector_done+581>:  fdivrp %st,%st(1)
0x0808fe0c  <disk_buffer_sector_done+583>:  fstpl  -0x28(%ebp)
```

Comment: What about `p currdisk->currangle + (simtime - seg->time) / currdisk->rotatetime`? (Prior to the `n` command, of course.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to formate the the text as code here, so I add the print output above.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: Linux platform, C language. GCC compiler.

Comment: My code is upload to git server: https://github.com/915086731/test.git   . After making, please run "./disksim parv.hpc3323 outv   ascii traceb  0 "

Comment: GDB isn't misreporting it. It's a [negative quiet NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Quiet_NaN).

Comment: @MikeDeSimone   Why it is equaled to a NaN? All the value and operations are normal.

Comment: I changed the code , add a temporary variable. No error occurs.
      double tmp1 = (simtime - seg->time) / currdisk->rotatetime;
      currdisk->currangle += tmp1;